# Conversion of latex to html for Word does not work

Tags: errors, conversion, tex4ht, htlatex

In order to get html code that is appropriate for Word I used the following command that I found on [a TUG page](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html):

```
htlatex filename "html,word" "symbol/!" "-cvalidate"
```

If I do this in Cygwin I get the following error message:

```
sh.exe": !": event not found
```

If I change the line to:

```
htlatex filename "html,word" "" "-cvalidate"
```

...I get:

```
--- warning --- Couldn't find font `5chr8t.htf' (char codes: 0--255)
[1 file main.html
--- error --- Can't find/open file `main.html'
```

Comment: please post the `mwe`

Comment: `!` is a special character on the bash command line you need `\!` (or single quotes) that is unrelated to the specific command being used